# Capturing and Triggering same event on Fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming

I want to capture an event and trigger it conditionally.

```
$('#next, #prev, .qpn').click( function(event){
    if (status[0]){
      submit_quiz($(currQ), 0);  
    }  
    else{
      setTimeout(function(){$( "body" ).trigger( event );}, 5000);
    }
});
```

I'm triggering but it's not getting triggered. Do I need to specify the element on which event was actually called like this:

```
$('#next').trigger("click")
```

How can get the element on which the event was originally called (in my case `$('#next')` or `$('#prev')` or `$('.qpn')`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the element like this:

```
$('#next, #prev, .qpn').click( function(event){
    var that=$(this);
    ...
```

and then trigger it like this:

```
that.trigger('click');
```

so your code should be like this:

```
$('#next, #prev, .qpn').click( function(event){
    var that=$(this);
    if (status[0]){
      submit_quiz($(currQ), 0);  
    }  
    else{
      setTimeout(function(){that.trigger( 'click' );}, 5000);
    }
});
```